# how to close a pop up when clicked on a webview

Tags: android

In my project i have a button in base layout which shows a popup
in one activity the base layout is inflating webview and in another activity it is inflating android mapview v2

the problem is the pop up doesn't close if i press outside the popup i.e in the webview or the mapview

i have used all these but still it doesn't work:

```
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

`pw.setTouchable(true);`

`pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());`

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` on your dialog instance

Comment: sorry im new to asking question in stackoverflow